# Creating order from Magento admin with custom price breaks custom option SKUs

Tags: magento

Please consider the situation where a product has extra SKU parts in it's custom options. The product may have a SKU `product` and the custom option has `option`, the end result will automatically be `product-option`.

Now go into the admin and attempt to order this product with a custom price, the custom option becomes an 'additional option' and the extra `-option` is missing. My store (enterprise 1.8) needs these SKUs to be intact but I need help making a fix for this. I expect I will have to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create` at some point and that's OK.

I've googled this problem until my fingers are numb but cannot even find mention of it let alone a confirmed fix. Please point me at the cause of the problem.

Comment: Can you say wich version of Magento CE matches EE 1.8 the closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was hard to track down because it seemed intermittent. I'm answering myself in detail because I don't want anyone else to go through the same ordeal.

---

The problem stemmed from custom options which both added a custom SKU and **contained a colon in their title**. If you look closely in the following picture you can just see two colons in "Colors::Black" - the first is the option's name, the second is added by Magento. When updating the order it attempts to parse the custom options back from that text box and the extra colon throws a spanner.

[image: Bad custom options]

The other bad thing is because Magento cannot read the custom option back that particular option gets dropped. In this case it's a required option, which leads to a warning message.

[image: broken custom option!]

Since the option is missing so is it's SKU part. Other custom options are not affected which clouds the issue. The simple answer to all this is to just avoid colons.